# Windows Workflow StateActivity Switching Performance

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation

We are having performance issues while switching between StateActivities in Windows Workflow. The workflow in question contains 14 StateActivities. There are two "main" activities that the user switches between regularly.

After profiling with ANTS I found that almost all of the time used switching between activities is spent Cloning the activities. I thought this would be a one time hit but it seems no matter how many times I switch the performance is roughly the same.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can improve the performance of switching between StateActivities?

[image: ANTS Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the performance problems with WF3.  The best option is to upgrade to WF4.

Comment: That is what I feared. As of right now we are stuck on 3.5 but I will get the ball rolling on moving to 4.0. Thanks.